# "gone there" vs "been there"

Tags: phrase-meaning, present-perfect, been-vs-gone

What's the difference between

> "I've **gone** there three times today"

and

> "I've **been** there three times today"

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, they mean the same thing. However, they don't have to.

> 1. I have **gone** to the store three times today. But each time, there was an accident and I was forced to return home before I got there.

Here, *gone* is being used in the same sense as *left for*. Although we would normally assume that you left for the store and *arrived* there, that doesn't always have to be the case. In the sense here, you would would more naturally say *I* ***tried to go***, or (as already stated) *I* ***left for***, but *I have* ***gone***, in this sense, is not actually incorrect.

---

> 2. I have **been** to the store three times times. Each time I got more of what I needed, but still forgot something.

In this sense, it actually is the case that you left for the store, arrived at the store, and spent some time at the store.

This is the same sense that *gone* typically conveys, even if it doesn't always. As with many things, context is important in understanding what's being communicated.

Comment: Hello Jason, I am just wondering what your take is on the difference between the two with regards to *"Has/have gone to refers to someone who has gone to a place but has not yet returned."*

Comment: @AIQ Neither word, on its own, says anything about there having been a return. You have to refer to context again for that.

Answer (score 1):

They both essentially mean the same thing in the sense that you were at a particular place today. That is a given. If you are talking to your friends casually, they both work equally well.

However, while nobody would question the use of *"I've been there three times today"* to mean that you went there and came back, there are many who would object to *"I've gone there three times today"* to mean the same thing.

Some often associate the use of "gone" with the person being somewhere else, away from the speaker. I myself choked when I read *"**I have gone** means you have gone **but haven't returned** three times, which would mean you are still there"* in anouk's answer. But then I looked into it.

Take a look at this [**post**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-have-been-gone-to-america-four-times.2600340/) in WordReference (WF).

> *"If you are here, in the present, you cannot use the present perfect "I have gone there" in speech because you cannot be in two places at once."* - Aardvark01

He said the past perfect would make sense with "gone": I had gone there three times today. Also, this wonderful answer in [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4985/what-is-the-difference-between-been-home-and-gone-home) by J.R. shows when we use the past perfect, both "been" and "gone" can be used to mean the same thing.

Here is what a different source, [ThoughtCo.](https://www.thoughtco.com/esl-have-gone-to-vs-have-been-to-4176485), says:

> *"Has/have gone to refers to someone who has gone to a place but has not yet returned. In other words, someone who has gone to Hawaii is still in Hawaii having a good time."*

There are some who recognize the nuance between the usage, but don't mind using either words (gone and been) when speaking casually.

---

Here are some helpful threads in ELL: [A](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132669/are-there-any-differences-between-have-been-on-a-trip-vs-have-gone-on-a-trip), [B](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4985/what-is-the-difference-between-been-home-and-gone-home), [ELL gone/been threads](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=gone%20been).

Here are some other threads in WF: [Been to/Gone to](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/been-to-gone-to.366671/), ["Been to" and "gone to" are never quite synonymous](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/gone-been.798579/).

Comment: "I have gone there three times today". said to someone implies you have gone and come back from the place three tiems.

Comment: Sure, I don't disagree with you in the sense that we both know what the speaker means. But is the use of "gone" in that sentence correct? Given the appropriateness of using "gone" in that sentence is debatable (as you can see from the linked sources), I think "been" is a safer choice. Would you agree? Oh, I should ask you, out of genuine curiosity, would you be okay with someone writing something similar to *"I have gone there three times today"* in a formal context to mean *"have gone and come back from the place three times"*?

Comment: Of course, it's correct. It is very common. "I've gone there three times today and they still refuse to give me an answer." [a government agency for example]

Comment: can I just say I didn't make this up, this was taught by an English teacher, a very good one.

Answer (score -1):

"I have been" means you have gone and returned three times and "I have gone" means you have gone but haven't returned three times, which would mean you are still there three times. I am not a native but I think it is probable that "gone" in this example is used like "been". Languages keep changing over time and the grammar is not always correct. Did you hear or read it somewhere?

Comment: **Gone there** and **been there** are two ways of saying the same thing although one or other may suit a particularly context better. **Been** suggests a longer stay than **gone**.

Comment: @RonaldSole - Looks like a valid answer to me.